# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, django-rest-auth

> The browser console keeps showing a 401 request error. I am trying to communicate with my API/backend which is django-rest-auth in order to display phlog manager when authenticated with auth-token. 
>   I cannot figure out why the authorization is not properly linking to my backend.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Navigate from '../headernavbarfooter/navigation';
import Home from '../pages/home';
import AboutUs from '../pages/about-us';
import SoupMenu from '../pages/soup-menu';
import BreakfastMenu from '../pages/breakfast-menu';
import LunchMenu from '../pages/lunch-menu';
import Phlog from '../pages/phlog';
import PhlogManager from '../pages/phlog-manager';
import Auth from '../pages/auth';


export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loggedInStatus: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN'
        };

        this.handleSuccessfulLogin = this.handleSuccessfulLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleUnsuccessfulLogin = this.handleUnsuccessfulLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleSuccessfulLogout = this.handleSuccessfulLogout.bind(this);
    }

    handleSuccessfulLogin() {
        this.setState({
            loggedInStatus: 'LOGGED_IN'
        });
    }

    handleUnsuccessfulLogin() {
        this.setState({
            loggedInStatus: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN'
        });
    }

    handleSuccessfulLogout() {
        this.setState({
            loggedInStatus: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN'
        });
    }
```

> This is where the error is targeting the problem. 
>   The axios request seems to be the source of the error.

```
    checkLoginStatus() {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.defaults.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`
        }
        return axios
            .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/"
            , {isAuthenticated: true}
            )
            .then(response => {
                const loggedInWithToken = response.data.keys;
                // console.log(loggedInWithToken);
                const loggedInStatus = this.state.loggedInStatus;

                if (loggedInWithToken && loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN') {
                    return loggedInWithToken;
                } else if (loggedInWithToken && loggedInStatus === 'NOT_LOGGED_IN') {
                    this.setState({
                        loggedInStatus: 'LOGGED_IN'
                    });
                } else if (!loggedInWithToken && loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN') {
                    this.setState({
                        loggedInStatus: 'NOT_LOGGED_IN'
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error', error);
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.checkLoginStatus();
    }

    adminPages() {
        return [
            <Route 
                key='phlog-manager'
                path='/phlog-manager'
                component={PhlogManager}
            />
        ];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Navigate 
                            loggedInStatus={this.state.loggedInStatus}
                            handleSuccessfulLogout={this.state.handleSuccessfulLogout}
                        />

                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                            <Route exact path='/about-us' component={AboutUs}/>
                            <Route 
                                path='/soups'
                                render={props => <SoupMenu {...props} />} /> 
                            <Route 
                                path='/breakfast-menu'
                                render={props => <BreakfastMenu {...props} />}/>
                            <Route 
                                path='/lunch-menu' 
                                render={props => <LunchMenu {...props}/>} />
                            <Route 
                                path='/phlog'
                                render={props => <Phlog {...props}/>} />

                            <Route 
                                path='/login'
                                render={props => (
                                    <Auth
                                        {...props}
                                        handleSuccessfulLogin={this.handleSuccessfulLogin}
                                        handleUnsuccessfulLogin={this.handleUnsuccessfulLogin}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />

                            {this.state.loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN'
                                ? this.props.adminPages()
                                : null
                            }

                            {/* <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUpForm} /> */}
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. I would advise you to open chrome dev tools and check the Network tab. Then try to login or whatever you do that causes 401 error and you should see which request fails with 401.

Comment: @TomasBruckner That is the peculiar part, is that the auth page isnt even showing up. But, in the network tab it shows a 304 status on my auth page.

Comment: can you reproduce the 401 error so it shows on the network tab?

Comment: @TomasBruckner No i cannot

Comment: @TomasBruckner I believe it may have to deal with axios.defaults.header according to docs